# Seaborn: title and subtitle placement

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

H all,

I'd like to create a scatterplot with a title, subtitle, colours corresponding to a specific variable and size corresponding to another variable. I want to display the colour legend but not the size. Here is what I have so far:

```
# imports
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# parameters
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = "roboto"
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# load data
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# plot
ax = sns.relplot(
    'sepal_length',
    'sepal_width',
    hue='species',
    size='petal_width',
    alpha=0.75,
    kind="scatter",
    legend=False,
    data=iris
)

# make adjustments
ax.set_axis_labels(x_var='Sepal Length', y_var='Sepal Width')
plt.text(x=4.7, y=4.7, s='Sepal Length vs Width', fontsize=16, weight='bold')
plt.text(x=4.7, y=4.6, s='The size of each point corresponds to sepal width', fontsize=8, alpha=0.75)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: scatterplot]

Here are my questions:

1) Is there a better way to set a subtitle? I tried this using `ax.suptitle("blah", y=1.05)` but it ends up sitting outside the scope of the figure. I don't like that I have to set x and y coordinates for my title/subtitle.

2) Is there a way for me to display the colour legend without showing the size legend? I would also like to be able to display this legend below the plot (or outside it). **if you can answer that question, I'll change the title of this post, mark your answer as complete and create another question about the titles and subtitles**

Many thanks!

Comment: It would be more appropriate to make 2 separate posts, 1 per question, instead of combining several questions in one.

Comment: I'm wondering whether you are looking for a solution that specifically uses `relplot()` and an underlying `FacetGrid`, even though the example graph that you are showing does not require said FacetGrid, and the same output could be produced by `sns.scatterplot()`

Comment: I don't really care about the method used to create the scatterplot, I just want it to be based on seaborn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `scatterplot()` makes it easier to manipulate the legend. If you use `legend='brief` then you'll get this legend:

[image]

You can get the artists and the labels used to create this legend using:

```
h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
```

since you only want the color info, and not the size, the solution is simply to recreate the legend using the first half of the artists

```
ax.legend(h[:4],l[:4])
```

Full code:

```
matplotlib.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
# load data
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))
sns.scatterplot(
    'sepal_length',
    'sepal_width',
    hue='species',
    size='petal_width',
    alpha=0.75,
    legend='brief',
    data=iris,
    ax=ax
)

# make adjustments
ax.set_xlabel('Sepal Length')
ax.set_ylabel('Sepal Width')

ax.text(x=0.5, y=1.1, s='Sepal Length vs Width', fontsize=16, weight='bold', ha='center', va='bottom', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(x=0.5, y=1.05, s='The size of each point corresponds to sepal width', fontsize=8, alpha=0.75, ha='center', va='bottom', transform=ax.transAxes)

h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h[:4],l[:4], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! :)